# Unable to get JSON response for post API with alamofire in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, codable

I have created generic methods in NetworkManager but this `serviceCall` working only .get method APIs
if i use post method with parameters like below got error

**error:**

```
{
code = "-32700";
meaning = "Undefined array key \"params\"";
message = "Parse error";
}


func testServiceCall(){

let parameters = ["name": "testinggg", "job": "manager"] as [String : Any]

let request = RequestObject(params: parameters, method: .post, path: "https://reqres.in/api/users", isTokenNeed: false, vc: self)
WebService.sharedInstance.serviceCall(UserModel.self, with: request) { (response, error) in
    print("user post response \(response)")
    
}
}
```

**This is NetworkManager Class**: here added parameters not working

```
class GeneralResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var jsonrpc: String
    var result: T?
    let error: ErrorClass?
}

struct ErrorClass: Codable {
    let code, message, meaning: String?
}

struct RequestObject {
    
    var params: [String: Any]?
    var method: HTTPMethod
    var path: String
    var isTokenNeed: Bool = false
    var vc: UIViewController?
}

class NetworkManager {

private let decoder: JSONDecoder
static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()

public init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) {
    self.decoder = decoder
}

public func serviceCall<T: Codable>(_ objectType: T.Type,
                                    
                                    with request: RequestObject,
                                    completion: @escaping  (T?, Error?) -> Void)  {
    
    AF.request(request.path, method: request.method, parameters: request.params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: request.isTokenNeed ? ["Authorization" : "Bearer hnjjdshjdsh", "Accept": "application/json"] : ["" : ""])
        .responseJSON { response in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                do {
                    let data = response.data
                    let responseData  = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: data ?? Data())
                    completion(responseData, nil)
                    
                } catch {
                    completion(nil, error)
                    print("in catch \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            case .failure(let AFError):
                let error = AFError
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("failure error: \(error)")
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `responseJSON{}`, it's deprecated. Especially, if you are retrieving inside the `response.data` & calling `JSONDecoder()`, because `responseJSON` will call a `JSONSerialization` for nothing. Instead use `responseDecodable()`.

Comment: @Larme, plz chk my code and correct the code. got stuck here from long

Comment: @Larme, added my postman response in my post now, plz chk

Comment: @Larme, did I miss initialize `params` or what?

Comment: There is no `"params"` in `let parameters =`... The parameters you're sending are different.

Comment: It should be at least `let parameters = ["params: ["name": "testinggg", "job": "manager"]]`